# CWAC-CAM2 : CameraActivity confirmation requires and action bar

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I try use [cwac-cam2](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2) library to take picture

Sample code:

```
Intent i = new CameraActivity.IntentBuilder(this)
                    .to(new File(getFilesDir(), "picture.jpg"))
                    .updateMediaStore()
                    .build();
```

Tested on :

1. Androin one marshmallow mito a10
2. Activity is extended from AppCompatActivity
3. Theme.AppCompat.Light

After click camera to take picture get error like below :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraActivity confirmation requires an action bar!
11-10 21:31:54.526 11278-11278/com.plugie.towing E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.commonsware.cwac.cam2.ConfirmationFragment.onHiddenChanged(ConfirmationFragment.java:84)
```

Comment: None of my activities extend from `AppCompatActivity`, and none of my activities use `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After read [cameraActivity document](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/blob/78cba67630f38df546bd063df9b044cb874866f4/docs/CameraActivity.md) I fix the error by adding the theme configuration for and CameraActivity in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<activity android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.cam2.CameraActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"/>
```